# What does the word "lines" mean in the phrase "tenure track lines"?

Tags: meaning

> The resources in the language department of most major research universities were assigned to different languages a very long time ago; resources such as budget, space, and *tenure track **lines***.

My guess is that, there are several candidates for a tenure, and they have to reach all sorts of required standards, so the lines refer to the standards of all aspects the candidates must reach. Is my guess right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At many American universities, every department is allotted a fixed number of slots for professors on the tenure track (assistant professors without tenure, associate professors, full professors with tenure). Each of these slots is called a *tenure track line*.

We can also say a department has 20 tenure track *positions* or 20 tenure track *slots* instead of 20 tenure track *lines*. We would not say that the department has 20 tenure tracks.

I believe the word *line* refers to the progression from assistant professor without tenure to (eventually) full professor with tenure. This is also exactly what *track* in *tenure track* refers to, but they are used differently, as described above.

Comment: Surely ***track*** ALSO refers to *the progression from assistant professor without tenure to (eventually) full professor with tenure*. Do you understand the two words *track* and *line* as having "different" meanings in the cited usage? And by implication, do you consider [*If you are on a **tenure line track,** knowing the weight ratio and what tenure and promotion committees value is vitally important*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tenure+line+track%22) to either be "invalid", or mean something different?

Comment: I believe the term *line* refers to a line (of type) in the institution's personnel budget.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, it has long been the case that each language group has its own department within the university.

Department of Romance Languages
Department of Germanic Languages
Department of Slavic Languages

Candidates are awarded or denied tenure by the university. It is quite common for a department to put forward a candidate and yet the candidate will be denied tenure. A department (but sometimes more than one department acting in concert) initiates the procedure and the university makes the decision based on various criteria.

We say that a person "is in line for tenure" or "on tenure track". Each department typically has its own line to tenure.

But promotion via the *tenure line* is just one path to promotion within a university. If the university has a medical school and teaching hospital, it will have a "medical center line" in addition to the tenure line.

The **line** is the **path** to promotion.

Comment: It's primarily AmE, not BrE, but so far as I can make out the "core" term is [*tenure **track***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tenure-track), not *tenure line*. So you might just as well say *the **track** is the **path** to promotion*. I think the addition of ***line*** is just a bit of clarifying repetition (as we refer to a *railway **track*** or *railway **line***, even though *way = track = line*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: a *tenure track line* is a slot for professors on the *tenure track*. We wouldn't say *"French has five tenure tracks,"* but we can say *"French has five tenure track lines."* This means that the department has given the French division permission to have up to five professors on the tenure track. And *track* and *line* indeed sound redundant here, but they don't mean quite the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. How I wish I could set both of your answers as accepted. :)